# Is there a way to get the path to the .bashrc file that has been used by BASH?

Tags: bashrc

I am logging into a server using a `.bashrc` file different from the one in `$HOME` or in `~/`. Since the server is huge and there is plenty of users folders, I really don't want to use `find` to look for any `.bashrc` that could be lurking in the HD. Is there a way to simply get the path to the `.bashrc` that has been used? Something like `which .bashrc`?

Comment: Could you indicate how you are logging into a server using a different `.bashrc` file? If you can edit it, [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14911318/1256347) might help.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I simply use ssh, but my PATH is different from the one specified in my local .bashrc, that is why I think another .bashrc must have being used.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your *actual* problem? I.e. that your PATH is different than you've set in the bashrc file.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I would prefer to keep it general. I really want to know if there is any procedure that can reveal the path of the .bashrc file that has been used. The content of the file doesn't really matter.

Comment: Well, in that case, does the answer I linked to earlier work? If not, why not?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke The output of the suggested solution is `I am in /xxx/xxx/users/xxx/-bash or I am in bashrc file.` This doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes but which one? I don't see a path to the .bashrc file. The path I get changes based on the folder I am in.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I haven't edited anything aside from the .bashrc file in my $HOME hoping to get that sourced, but it is not. Now I would like to know which .bashrc has been sourced. Is there a way to get that info or not? The question is pretty much straight forward. I would like not to digress from it.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I have deleted the .bashrc file from my $HOME. I logged out and in again. I have run the command once more, I got the same output. So, Is there a way to know the path of the sourced file?

Comment: Well, it is not sourced. And I have established that already in my original question. I want to figure out which one is the sourced file!

Comment: My bad. Sorry about that.

Comment: When you say "I simply use ssh, but my PATH is different from the one specified in my local `.bashrc`", by "local" do you mean the machine you `ssh` from? In the context of logging into a remote server, the client is local. It's normal your local startup scripts are not available for any shell running on the remote machine.

Comment: By local I mean my userspace ($HOME folder) on the remote server, not my laptop.